# Java creating a time class

Tags: java

After creating a new Time class I encountered an error trying to type the last method:

```
public class Time1
{
    private int _hour;
    private int _minute;

    public Time1(int h,int m)
    {
        if(h>=0 && h<=23)
        this._hour=h;
        else
        this._hour=0;

        if(m>=0 && m<=59)
        this._minute=m;
        else
        this._minute=0;


    }

public Time1(Time1 other)
{
    this._hour=other._hour;
    this._minute=other._minute;
}

public String toString()
{
    String s,t;

    if(_hour<10)
    s="0";
    else
    s="";
    if(_minute<10)
    t="0";
    else
    t="";
    return s+_hour+":"+t+_minute;
}



   public int minFromMidnight()
    {
        int minFromMidnight;
        minFromMidnight=(((this._hour)*60)+(this._minute));
        return minFromMidnight;
    }
```

and now lastly using some of those methods I'm trying to produce the next:

```
Time1 addMinutes(int num) /*requested to be called as this in the project*/

Time1 addMinutes=new Time1();

this._minute=(minFromMidnight()+num)&60;

return addMinutes;
```

and the second question probably my misunderstanding since I lack probably many basics

```
/*Public Time1 (Time1 t)*/
/*a constructor that gets a different time and copies its values*/
```

for some reason I don't really get it.do they request to build another other._hour but with a T instead of Other?

will gladly accept any advice and help!
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the original assignment you have to do, so we know what your task is. Also explain in detail what the question is or what the problem is.

Comment: If this is a training exercise, it’s a good one. For production code one would not develop one’s own class for a time if day but would use the built-in [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious you want to build one of your own, so I won't direct you to the existing implementations.  However, if you want to use an existing implementation, look into [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)

There are many kinds of times.  For clarity, I'll assume you mean a Duration, which is roughly "how much time has passed, without specifying when it started".

Remember that there is no need to store the time the way you format it.  That's one of the points of Object-Orientation, data hiding of the internal structure.

For simplicity, let's redefine the internals as "Durations are just a number of seconds."  The reason to do this is to make it much easier to do time calculations.  Adding time to our duration will just be adding seconds together, and subtracting time from our Duration will just be subtracting seconds from each other.

```
public class Duration {
   private long seconds;

   public Duration add(Duration other) {
       // notice this is implemented in the class, so it can get
       // the other instance's private variables.
       return new Duration(seconds + other.seconds); 
   }  

}
```

The rest is just deciding on constructors, and dividing up the seconds for proper formatting for `toString()`.  I suggest you use the `printf` style string formatter, as it is easier than doing the zero padding yourself.

Comment: Pay attention that this implementation permits negative durations; but, you can adjust the ideas to fit your specific needs as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize int minFromMidnight to a value because it is inside a method. Only class variables are initialized to their default values. int is initialized to 0. But in this method scope, it won't be initilized. You have to do that.

```
public int minFromMidnight()
    {
        int minFromMidnight = 0;
        minFromMidnight=(((this._hour)*60)+(this._minute));
        return minFromMidnight;
    }
```

Public Time1 (Time1 t) and Public Time1 (Time1 other) are the same thing. Your object created from the class gets a default constructor.

```
Time1 t = new Time1();
//assign values and pass it to
```

Or Time1 t = new Time1(1,2); // Your hour and minutes

```
Time1 t1 = new Time(t);
```

So t1 will assign instance values of t variables to t1 according to your constructor in order.

Comment: Assigning a value to `minFromMidnight` in the line following the declaration works fine. First initializing it to 0 and then assigning its proper value just confuses things.